# Firebase email / password createUser security

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I'm using Firebase 2.x. If I enable email/password security, how do I prevent a malicious pre-existing user from writing their own javascript code that would do authenticate with my Firebase and then launch a createUser attack? Hypothetically, it might look like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(my_fire_base);
ref.authWithPassword({ email : 'pre@existing.com', password: 'validpassword' },
    function(error, authData) { 
        if (!error) { 
             ref.createUser( ... ); // do this a bunch of times
        }
    });
```

Comment: I may be missing your use-case here, but why do you put the email/password in the code? You'd prevent by not including the credentials in the code.

Comment: I wouldn't be putting in credentials in the code. This would be an example of malicious code written by a validated user of the system. There's no documentation on firebase that says if the createuser call is limited to admin tokens or originating from a specific domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was [cross-posted to Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sN-OLlmO43k), I'll quote the answer that was given [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sN-OLlmO43k):

> You do not need to be authenticated to call createUser(). This is by design and how all registration systems work. It is possible for a malicious client to call createUser() a gazillion times, but this is where we build rate limiting into the service we provide and prevent people from doing this. You cannot restrict by specific origins, and even if you could, as you mentioned, this can be easily spoofed.